# Creating userform based on nodes in XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have dinamicaly generated buttons on one of my userforms. The buttons are being generated based on nodes in an xml file.

```
    namespace e2e_template
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3(string data)
        {
            string Username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();

           string Result = Username.Length <= 4 ? "" : Username.Substring(4);


            string Path = $"C:\\Users\\{Result}\\Documents\\template\\config.xml";
            //MessageBox.Show(Path);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Path);
            XmlNodeList templates = doc.SelectNodes("//template");


            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;


           foreach (XmlNode template in templates)
            {
                string name = template.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText.Trim();
                Button button = new Button
                {
                    Text = name,
                    Width = 250,
                    Height = 75,
                    Left = x + 20,
                    Top = y,
                };
                button.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
                Controls.Add(button);
              y += button.Height + 5;
            }
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form4 form = new Form4();
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
    }

}
```

I would like that when I click on a button and is opening a new userform (form4 in this case) I would like to show text between other nodes.However theare are few "template" nodes in the XML file.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<template id="Some Template ID">

      <name>Template name</name>
      <description>Discription of this template</description>
      <item id="1">1st item of this template</item>
      <item id="2">2nd item of this template</item>
      <item id="3">3rd item of this template</item>
      <item id="4">4th item of this template</item>

    </template>
```

So if I click on the button with caption for example "Template name" it will open user form4 as it does now, but I would see the item ID listed 1 under another. but the tricky part is that the number of IDs are different. I mean there can be 4 but also 10. how should I approach this problem?

Comment: what's the parent node of `template` node?

Comment: the parent node is "templates" and under "templates" we have few "template" nodes. under "template" nodes we have "name" nodes and under "name" nodes we have "item id" nodes.

Comment: I added my answer below try it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, 
Create a one class,

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create a public property in your Form4 like

```
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Then modify your code like below to get details of particular template to form4

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Path to your xml file");

    string buttonText = (sender as Button).Text;

    string description = xDoc.Descendants("template").Where(x => x.Element("name").Value == buttonText).Select(x => x.Element("description").Value).FirstOrDefault();

    var listofItems = xDoc.Descendants("template").Where(x => x.Element("name").Value == buttonText).SelectMany(x => x.Elements("item")).Select(y => new Item { Id = y.Attribute("id").Value, Name = y.Value });

    Form4 form = new Form4();

    form.Description = description;
    form.Items = listofItems.ToList();

    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

And now Description and Items have values on Form4 and then you can use it in your way.

Comment: when I try to modify the code based on yours I'm getting several error messages for example (Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0053 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'List<Item>' is less accessible than property 'Form4.Items' or Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'XDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" can you help with these?

Comment: Use this namespace to get rid from `XDocument` related error => `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: Are you getting severity error for only `Items`  property and not for `Description` property, right?

Comment: Try to make `Item` class also `public`

Comment: and now a new one "
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Item>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Use like this => "form.Items = listofItems.ToList();"

Comment: I'm not receiveing error messages anymore, however form4 is totally empty now, but before I could see the nodes there, but all of them and not just the ones under the specific name nodes.

Comment: Try to remove `.Trim();` in your `foreach (XmlNode template in templates)` from `InnerText` and try again

Comment: Also verify that, Is `name` is unique for each of `template` otherwise most probably you'll get more that one template and also check in `Button_Click` event is there `buttonText` is same as template name or is any whitespace or hidden characters present and that's why you can't get specific template